# How to include more than 1 model object in a strongly typed view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, object

When I create a strongly-typed view from an ActionResult function, the Visual Studio dialog for creating views only allow me to include one model object.

How do I include more than 1 so I can use intelli-sense for all of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It`s not possible. You should create another Model to wrap this two models.

Example:

```
//Model

public class FooModel1
{
   public string Property {get;set;}
}

public class FooModel2
{
   public string Property {get;set;}    
}

public class FooModel
{
  public FooModel1 One {get;set;}
  public FooModel2 Two {get;set;}
}
```

//Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var model = new FooModel() { One = new FooModel1 (), Two = new FooModel2 ()};
   return View(model);
}
```

//View

```
@model FooModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.One.Property)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Two.Property)
```